# Highcharts context menu doesnt show

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts, contextmenu

Most people asked how to disable the context menu in Highcharts. My problem is that it doesnt show at all. The exporting.js is included in the HTML where the container for the chart is.

My Backend is in Ruby respectively in Ruby on Rails.

My Code:

```
var myChart = Highcharts.chart({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                renderTo: container[0]
            },
            colors: [
                '#B0171F', '#DC143C', '#8B008B', '#4B0082', '#9370DB',
                '#0000FF', '#708090', '#1E90FF', '#00F5FF', '#00FFFF',
                '#00FF7F', '#2E8B57', '#00FF00', '#7CFC00', '#FFFF00',
                '#FFD700', '#FFA500', '#EE7600', '#FF4500', '#FF0000',
                '#7171C6', '#8E8E38', '#1E1E1E', '#D926D9', '#E085E0',
                '#F20D80', '#1F1F47', '#19334D', '#1F4747', '#293D33'
            ],
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                tickInterval: 150,
                title: {
                    text: 'Zeit'
                },
                categories: ["Test"]
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Distanz in Meter'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: 'm'
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enable: true,
                    align: 'left'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                showInLegend: false,
                name: 'Series 1',
                turboThreshold: 5000
            }]
        });
};
```

**EDIT**
For everyone using Highcharts with Ruby on Rails: 
add "//= require highcharts/modules/exporting" to your application.js

Comment: Is this the full code? How do you include exporting.js? On jsfiddle context menu works https://jsfiddle.net/8q3c8tmL/

Comment: @morganfree i include the exporting.js in the html where the div with the container is. And its not the full code, because i load the series and categories seperately. Also i include highcharts in my Gemfile and not with the scripttag as the exporting.js, but i guess that shouldnt be the problem.

Comment: I just found out that the exporting.js is already included by the highcharts gem, but i dont get why it doesnt show the context menu then